# How to fetch update binary URL from Microsoft Update Catalog web-page?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to fetch download URL of update binaries from Microsoft Update Catalog web-page. The download button taking me to a new window on which I have the target binary URL is present.

How can I fetch the binary URL by parsing the catalog web page.

I tried the following way

```python
import urllib.request

def main():
    url = 'https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3205400'
    offlinePage = 'catalog.html'
    print(url)
    sourceWebPage(url, offlinePage)

def sourceWebPage(url, offlinePage):
    request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()
    with open(offlinePage, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the saved HTML source file is not having any link to the target binary URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="431bdad0-e68b-4275-8f14-e9c90fa2a9b0_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="goToDetails(&quot;431bdad0-e68b-4275-8f14-e9c90fa2a9b0&quot;);">
```

The download pop-up window is generated by JavaScript, you can not use `requests` or `urllib` to handle JavaScript. I recommend you use selenium..

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Is there any other way out ? Without Selenium can't I execute JavaScript inline and go to the next page ?

Comment: @Alen Nishabu Javascript is running on the browser, so you can not execute JavaScript inline

Comment: Okay, AFAIK Selenium would require to load a browser to perform actions. I need a way without invoking a visible instance of any browser. Something like urllib..

Comment: @Alen Nishabu Selenium + PhantomJS. PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

Comment: @ 宏杰李 That's great, Thanks a lot.
How about using PyQt for this task ? I just need the HTML source code after evaluating the JavaScripts like onClick() functions and others

Comment: @Alen Nishabu  selenium can do that too, we usually combine the selenium and Beautifulsoup to web scraping.

Comment: @Alen please accept this answer to close this question.